# Align flexbox items horizontally with unwrappable variable-width item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to align three items in a flexbox like this. The context is that these are unknown-length (but wrappable) labels for an unknown-width (unwrappable) slider/row of buttons in a survey.

`[L]         [R]
[variable width]`

How do I align the top two items to the width of the lower/*middle* item without fixing the width of the container to the (in reality unknown width of the *middle* item)?

I considered putting *left* and *right* into another flexbox and using a column layout for the top container. I don't like that way, because I'd have to break with the true content order (left-middle-right), but I couldn't even make it work this way.

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px; /* I want to get rid of this */
}

.left {
  order: 1;
  flex: 1 0;
}

.right {
  order: 2;
  flex: 1 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.middle {
  order: 3;
  flex: 2 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    Some unknown-width unwrappable thing here.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right label may wrap if it's wider than 50%
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you against using `position:absolute` for the left / right content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only pure CSS possibility to align items as you want is CSS Grid.

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted;
}

.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content;
}

.right {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.middle {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    Some unknown-width unwrappable thing here.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right label may wrap if it's wider than 50%
  </div>
</div>
```

Also if you need IE10+ support it's easy to achieve:

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted;
}

.container {
  display: -ms-inline-grid;
  display: inline-grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: min-content min-content;
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content;
}

.right {
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.middle {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    Some unknown-width unwrappable thing here.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right label may wrap if it's wider than 50%
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about CSS grid, so thanks especially for ignoring the title of my question asking for a flexbox solution ;-) This checks all the boxes. In my real problem, the width computation governing the middle element changed with this solution for some reason, but I'll be able to figure that out on my own.

Comment: I didn't notice this earlier, but here again, the bottom/middle element does not govern the width of the whole: https://jsfiddle.net/8nofar40/
I'm not sure what the rule is, though. Can I get the middle element to always be the deciding factor?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea of solution without adding extra markup:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 20px;
}

.left {
  order: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  width: 0.5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.right {
  order: 2;
  min-width: 0;
  width: 0.5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.middle {
  order: 3;
  flex-basis: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    some left content
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    So in my real example, there is some unknown-width unwrappable thing here. there is some unknown-width unwrappable thing here.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    some right content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    some left content
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    So in my real example, there is some unknown-width unwrappable thing here.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    So in my real example, there is.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    So in my
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

But if you are ok to slightly adjust the HTML you can try something like this:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 20px;
}

.sub {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub">
    <div class="left">
      some left content
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      some right content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    So in my real example, there is some unknown-width unwrappable thing here. there is some unknown-width unwrappable thing here.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub">
    <div class="left">
      some left content
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      some right content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    So in my real example, there is some unk
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub">
    <div class="left">
      left
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      right
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    So in my real example,
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great and solves my fiddle, thank you. Now, on to understand why it works and trying to apply it to my real problem (doesn't quite work yet).

Comment: I hit one snag: When left/right can wrap, but don't need to, they now do so prematurely because of the hack. https://jsfiddle.net/y7mcmxtf/14/

Comment: @Ruben ok i see, we can use white-space:nowrap in this case

Comment: @Ruben but they will overflow then https://jsfiddle.net/y7mcmxtf/24/ .. ok will thnk about an alternative ;)

Comment: @Ruben i added another way but was obliged to split the content into two different container

Comment: With this new way, the left/right elements never wrap, but I need the width to be governed by the middle element. If the right+left are wider (unwrapped) than middle, they go out of alignment.

Comment: @Ruben well am out of hacks for this one :) by they way i don't think it's possible to meet all the need requirements because some of the are contradictory

Comment: Really? Like what? All my needs would be met, if I knew the width of the middle element (e.g. I could easily hack this with JS, and it's easy with tables https://jsfiddle.net/4z7qxfx6/2/ ). But yeah, I also have no idea how to do it with CSS.

Comment: @Ruben of course with JS it's easy :) also with table but not easy with flex and actualy layout ... it's very hard to specify that both element need to fit within a width of a third element and also behave normally within that width [wrap if needed]

Comment: Maybe I'll try some disgusting combination of display table and flexbox later. But this would probably require me to mess with the order and nesting of divs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `flex` can be configured like that. The effect you are looking for can be achieved using `position:absolute` on the left/right elements:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left,
.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}

.middle {}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    So in my real example, there is some unknown-width unwrappable thing here.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not bad, but this could make the `left` and `right` labels run into each other, if they are longer, right? They have unknown contents, too. I'll fix my example to show this, because I think this is one reason to prefer flebox.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `flex` from `auto` to `100%`, and add `text-align: center` to `.middle`, like so:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.left {
  order: 1;
  flex: 1 0;
}

.right {
  order: 2;
  flex: 1 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.middle {
  order: 3;
  flex: 2 0 100%; /* change this to 100% instead of auto */
  text-align: center; /* To center the text */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    So in my real example, there is some unknown-width unwrappable thing here.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But that's not the layout I want.

Answer (score -1):

Use `flex-basis: number%` it works very well and supported by IE 10+, and you can choose your breaking point in media query selectors if you want.

check my code:

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left {
  flex-basis: 49.55%; /* change this to whatever you want */
}

.right {
  flex-basis: 49.55%; /* change this to whatever you want */
}

.middle {
  order: 3;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    Some unknown-width unwrappable thing here.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right label may wrap if it's wider than 50%
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your own code example shows that this doesn't reproduce my desired output. Now the right element doesn't wrap and the total width is governed by the right width times two rather than the middle element width.